# How do I change the add new link in a webpart?

Tags: web-part, wiki-pages

I have created two pages within my site that consist of custom list web parts with summary toolbar enabled.

The problem I'm having is that this is appearing in two completely separate ways and I'm not sure what is causing this or how to make them consistent.

**Page 1 web part summary toolbar:**
[image]

as you can see this link appears at the top of the web part.

**Page 2 web part summary toolbar:**

[image]

Where as on the second page they appear at the bottom and looks completely different. Can anyone explain why this is happening or know a way I can make these identical?

Comment: Probably your second one is a 'lookup' column to another list or document library - the column is being 'borrowed'.  You can check whether this is the case by going in to the List Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be due to the number of items in the list. I added a tone of records and reapplied the summary toolbar. This made the link in image 2 the same as in image 1 then I just deleted the blag records.